UQI and VIF as image generation metrics
The aricle briefly describes various metrics for image generative models. It categorizes them into pixel-, feature-, task- and novelty-based metrics.
Following such categorization I understand that A Universal Quality Image Index (UQI) is a pixel-based metric and then what about Visual information fidelity (VIF)?
